# Then the [noun] will vs. the [noun] will then

Tags: grammar

I was just writing something and came across these two alternations of saying this, and was curious what the difference between them is, and if one of them is technically incorrect.

After a quick google and search here didn't yield any obvious answers, I'm asking all of you!

... then the contestant will attempt to ....

vs

... the contestant will then attempt to ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Then' means '[at] the time'.  It is used here adverbially, which means that it can be moved around the clause without changing the meaning. (Just don't move it inside an NP)

examples:
Then he will attempt to jump.
He will then attempt to jump.
He will attempt then to jump.
He will attempt to then jump.
He will attempt to jump then.

Comma[s] around 'then' are also allowed, and clarify that it is adverbial.